# Which data access technology is better for DocumentDB

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I'm creating a website content management system which stores a whole bunch of website articles and let user be able to modify these articles through the system. I'm a typical SQL Server developer however I'm thinking maybe this system can be done in DocumentDB.
We are using C# plus WebAPI to do the read and write. I'm testing different data access technology to see which one performs better. I have been trying Ling, Linq Lambda, SQL and Stored Procedure. The thing is all these query methods seems all running around 600ms to 700ms when I test via Postman. For example, one of my test is a simple Get http://localhost:xxxxxx/multilanguage/resources/1, which would take 600ms+. That was only a 1 kb document and there are only have 5 documents stored in my collection so far. 
 So I guess what I want to ask is: is there a quicker way to query DocumentDB than this. The reason I ask is because I did something similar in SQL Server before(not to query document, it was for relational tables). A much more complex query in a stored procedure on multiple joined tables only takes around 300ms. So I guess there should be a quicker way to do this. 
Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Welcome to SO. As it stands, there isn't really much information in the question nor is it specific enough to be able to provide a meaningful answer. Questions like "what's faster/better" are [not considered good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Have a look at [*How do I ask a good question*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and re-frame your question accordingly.

Comment: I have long suspected that there is a some issue associated with the network boundary that causes high latency for HTTP calls to DocumentDB. I use node.js which only talks over HTTP. When I run from my house I see a minimum of 250ms round trip. However, Azure also hosts node.js in the same data centers as DocumentDB and the latency from those calls is sub-10ms. I haven't worried about it much because my production node.js environment is in Azure data centers. It only effects our live tests and ad-hoc exploratory work.

Comment: On the .NET side, though, I understand the direct TCP connection has much lower latency.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably if you will change implementation to stab you will get same performance since actually you are testing connection time between yours server and client (postman).

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things you can do, but do keep in mind that DocumentDB, and other NoSQL solutions behave very differently than standard SQL Server.  For example, the more nodes and RAM available to DocumentDB the better it will perform overall.  The development instance of DocumentDB on Azure is understandably going to use fewer resources than a production instance.  Since Azure takes care of scaling, one way to think about it is that the more data you have the better it will perform.

That said, something you are probably not used to is sharing your connection object for your whole application.  That avoids the start up penalties every time you want to get your data.  Summarizing [Performance Tips](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/performance-tips-for-azure-documentdb-part-1-2/):

- Use TCP connection instead of HTTPS when you can
- Use `await client.OpenAsync()` to avoid pausing on start up latency for the first request
- Connect to the DocumentDB in the same region (keep in mind if you host across regions)
- Use a singleton to access DocumentDB (it's threadsafe)
- Cache your SelfLinks for quick access
- Tune your page sizes so that you get only the data you intend to use

The more advanced [performance tips](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/performance-tips-for-azure-documentdb-part-2/) cover index policies, etc.  DocumentDB and other NoSQL databases behave differently than SQL databases.  That also means your assumptions about how the APIs work are probably wrong.  Make sure you are testing similar concepts.  The SQL Server database connection object needs you to create/dispose of objects for each transaction so it can return those connections back to a connection pool.  Treating DocumentDB the same way is going to cause the same kind of performance problems as if you didn't use a connection pool.

Comment: When DocumentDB first came out, we were caching self-links but since they introduced id-based routing, we build them from the id's which we generate client-side and/or retain locally. We have not seen any loss in performance from using id-based routing.

Comment: @LarryMaccherone, I've spent more time with ElasticSearch, so I'll take your word for it with the self-links.  The basic point is that the way you test and interact with NoSQL is very different than the way you do it with SQL databases.  I'm sure the backbone within a region has very high bandwidth, so the connection speed issues are much less of a problem.